# New laptop battery has a lump or bulge about 1 cm across - is this a damaged battery?

Tags: laptop, battery

I've ordered a new 3rd party battery for an old laptop.

After unpacking I could feel a lump in the middle of the battery about 1 cm across, something under the plastic however the plastic hasn't cracked.

The battery charged fine.

Googling I found lots of Macbook battery issues.  Is this similar? Should I return it?

If it's cosmetic, I'm not fussed. But I am concerned if it will blow up or damage the laptop.

Comment: Including a picture would be helpful, but if you're worried why not send it back?

Comment: To help improve future questions/answers, include as much detail as possible. For instance, if you include brand and model information, someone who is familiar with it can give you a complete answer to your question. As @slhck stated, pictures help greatly.

Comment: I'll add a photo this evening.  The battery is some random brand from Smart Parts UK, via Amazon UK

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know if the issue is cosmetic or a problem with one of the Li-Ion cells within the battery unless you take it apart and peep inside. If in doubt return it and ask for a replacement.

That said, if one of the cells is damaged, the battery will not give you the promised hours of running time as its power retention capacity is reduced.